# WebRTC in iPhone (gas-preprocessor issues)

Tags: iphone, assembly, compilation, gnu-assembler, webrtc

I'm trying compile the lastest WebRTC version for iPhone. I not need to compile the entire solution, I only need to compile the VAD module.

To do that, I have created a Xcode project and I have tried to compile the source necessary, but I have a problem with the *.s files and its assembler.

Like in the FFMPEG library, I know that I must "translate" the assembler code to an assembler code that the gcc for iPhone understand, but I don't know how I do this manually.

I have tried to create a configure file and set in it "as=gas-preprocessor.pl" (like in FFMPEG), but does not work.

Any idea? How do I run the gas-preprocessor.pl manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just finishing it on iOS and has built standalone static libraries of NS/VAD/AECM and AGC, here's some tips for you, and hope you success:

**1. Source File List**

for standalone VAD build, you should make sure your project has all of these files(no .s file needed), and I'm not listed the `header files` here, you will get some `header file can not be found` errors, just fixing it and things will be done.)

```
webrtc_vad.c
vad_core.c
vad_filterbank.c
vad_gmm.c
vad_sp.c
real_fft.c
division_operations.c
complex_bit_reverse.c
cross_correlation.c
complex_fft.c
downsample_fast.c
vector_scaling_operations.c
get_scaling_square.c
energy.c
min_max_operations.c
spl_init.c
```

**2. Adding a macro called** `WEBRTC_MAC`

I'm not sure why the Xcode environment does not provide this macro, but it should be defined to ensure that `WEBRTC_POSIX` is enabled. To define this macro, adding it to a new header file or just define it in the webrtc-header-files.

**3. Following *[these steps](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/)* to build and setup a static library of WebRTC-VAD module on iOS**

`notice`, do not use LLVM 2.0 to compile the VAD module(use GCC or LLVM GCC). cus' it can throw you lots of errors when compiling some webrtc variable declarations.

**4. Using the libwebrtc_vad.a**

if you got this far, things are easy to go, just include `webrtc_vad.h` and using the API provided by this module. and vad is working fine in my case.

hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

try to check this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/discuss-webrtc/VJg-fk2-i_0 i believe you have to set inline assembly correctly. I am also onto this so let me know if you want to switch emails or something.