# Built-in AEC or WebRTC AEC on iOS?

Tags: ios, webrtc, aec

I'm new to iOS(from android). I have already successfully do the AEC process on android with WebRTC standalone AECM module.

Now I have to do the same thing on iOS but with little progress. the mainly problem is which solution should I choose to do the AEC on iOS:

1. using iOS built-in AEC.
2. using WebRTC standalone AECM module again.

for the first solution, I've learnt that iOS has built-in AEC in Voice Processing I/O unit. but I heard that the performance of VPU is not good enough. does it?

for the second one, on android, i can use AudioRecord and AudioTrack's API and some buffer techniche to calculate the "delay" described in WebRTC "audio_processing.h", but I have no info. about what API should I use to calc the same delay on iOS.

I'm keep searching on google and iOS docs right now. but also eager for any advise here. especially some one who did the AEC on iOS already.

thanks a lot.

Comment: after look into "audio_device_ios", i found out that they use Audio Unit to handle the delay things.

Comment: Do you able to successful create the webrtc for IOS? I am trying to work on webrtc for IOS.But not getting hte exact  material.Please guide me if there is any chances to do the webrtc in IOS or other option for it

Comment: @IOSDeveloper i just build standalone webrtc_aecm/ns/vad modules, not the whole webrtc VOE on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please explain me the difference between the standalone webrtc_aecm/ns/vad and webrtc VOE.

Comment: these modules are integrated into voice engine, and worked together to get a better voice procession effect. but we can just use one or two of them to do our own specified things. if i just wanna detecting active voice, i think VAD is enough. BTW, use standalone AECM module is not a good way, cus' there's more difficulty on delay estimating than the whole VOE.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.So there is no other way for webrtc in IOS as per you knowledge?

Comment: yep, as i know, there's a [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/VJg-fk2-i_0) on how to compile the webrtc for iOS, and can also find some [tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257546/building-webrtc-on-ios) in SO. WebRTC is still in developing, and i'm not sync from google about 1 mounth, so i don't know if there is a iOS edition of WebRTC right now.

Comment: and if you finally find a way to make a iOS edition of WebRTC, please feedback here or google group, thanks a lot. ;)

Comment: thanks .I will surely write it over here if i get something for webrtc in IOS :)

Comment: is there any chances for rejection of the application form apple store by using webrtc ? DO you experince such issue?

Comment: sorry i'm not a pro iOS developer, so i don't know what kind of rejection you're talking about. can you clarify it? dynamic library in iOS? or what

Comment: When we upload the applicaiton in apple store.they review the code.and if there is some 3rd party is been used which accordinge to them is not proper then they reject the applciaiton... Its apple rule..Its fine i will check that...any way thanks alot for sharing .. :)

Comment: i see... but i already see some iPhone app in github that uses WebRTC or libjingle. so i guess there's no such rejections on it.