# Error building the webrtc code on mac

Tags: macos, webrtc

This is the error:

```
sys/cdefs.h' file not found
```

what i've done is just follow the offical steps,the" gclient sync --force" prompt the following errors:

```
In file included from /Users/ted/Desktop/webrtcSrc/WD/trunk/third_party/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_fake_stack.cc:14:
In file included from /Users/ted/Desktop/webrtcSrc/WD/trunk/third_party/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_allocator.h:19:
In file included from /Users/ted/Desktop/webrtcSrc/WD/trunk/third_party/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_interceptors.h:18:
/Users/ted/Desktop/webrtcSrc/WD/trunk/third_party/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/interception/interception.h:90:10: fatal error: 'sys/cdefs.h' file not found
```

=====
what the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On Mavericks? Try typing "xcode-select --install" to pop up the dialog to install the Xcode command-line tools. That should give you a /usr/include directory and then building LLVM should work.

Ref: http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Naive-Mavericks-Trunk-Build-Errors-td4035480.html